Jetback compose Room
I am trying to build room in jetpack compose using android studio version 2023 but I can not do it correctly so I need good developer to summarize the way to create room successfully in simple steps by code
I except to see the database in app Inspector but the database didn't appear and cat log say that the app can't implement 

Check out the tutorial on youtube. there are many examples

Check this codelab from google it shows you how to use room in compose, it is very easy with less than 5 to 6 steps

Add dependencies
Declare entities(data classes)
Declare DAO(interfaces for all your database queries)
Add Repository to access DAO
A ViewModel to access data from your UI
In Compose use viewModel to get database entries as StateFlow

If you use any DI it will be much more easier like in my case I use koin-annotations
